# Unwanted white space in two columns article LaTeX

Tags: spacing, graphics, two-column

I'm writing an article with 2 columns, but unfortunately, after add the images, the space between titles, sections etc were modified, adding many white spaces. How can I solve it?

My code:

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    bookmarksnumbered,
    citecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    bookmarksopen=true}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[comma,authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%para usar titlespacing e titleformat
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\sloppy
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{authblk}
\renewcommand*{\Authands}{ \& }
\renewcommand*{\Authand}{ \& }
\titlespacing*{\part}{0cm}{10pt}{10pt} %espaçamento dos titulos e o texto
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{10pt}{100pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0cm}{10pt}{10pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0cm}{10pt}{10pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0cm}{10pt}{10pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%
%
%
\begin{document}
    \title{\textbf{A title for the example}}
    \author[1]{Author One}
    \author[2,$\bigstar$]{Author Two}
    \affil[1]{\textit{University of One}}
    \affil[2]{\textit{University of Two}}
    \affil[$\bigstar$]{\textit{Some Notes}}
    \maketitle
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{abstract}
        An Abstract
    \end{abstract}
    %
    \section{Introdução}
    \subsection{Contexto}
\blindtext\par
    %
\blindtext\par
%
\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \centering
    \makebox[\linewidth]{This} \par
    \makebox[\linewidth]{is} \par
    \makebox[\linewidth]{a} \par
    \makebox[\linewidth]{simple} \par
    \makebox[\linewidth]{figure} \par
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}
%
And here goes a big figure for ilustrate my problem with the spaces\par
\begin{figure*}[tbh]
    \centering
    \makebox[\linewidth]{This} \par
    \makebox[\linewidth]{is} \par
    \makebox[\linewidth]{the} \par
    \makebox[\linewidth]{big} \par
    \makebox[\linewidth]{figure} \par
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure*}
%
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

And here is the unwanted result
[image]

Comment: Try `\raggedbottom` at the start of your document.

Comment: @TeXnician it didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the following line:

```
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{10pt}{100pt}
```

which asks for 100pt space after a section. Just change it to

```
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{10pt}{10pt}
```

Comment: A few seconds to slow ...  // I would like to add, that you (OP) should clean up your header, there are several warnings of packages that might not work together.

Comment: Oh my God, I didn't see it. Was a writing mistake. Sorry and thanks